# Searching XML column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Trying to search column Data, its an xml column

```
[dbo].[HistoryData].[Data].exist('//text()[CONTAINS(., 'Request viewed' )]') = 1
```

I get error Incorrect syntax near 'Request'. What am i missing here? kindly assist.

Column Data has this:

```
<MessageNotification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<AttorneyID xsi:nil="true" />
<MatterID xsi:nil="true" />
<NotificationID xsi:nil="true" />
<MessageId>3566913</MessageId>
<ParentMessageGuid xsi:nil="true" />
<MessageGuid>fc54e518-e45d-4564-8b80-2593796d5b</MessageGuid>
<Subject>Firm not registered </Subject>
<MessageDate>2015-06-19T10:05:48.4493646+02:00</MessageDate><Body>

This is just a message

Thank you

</Body>
<ContactPerson> N/A </ContactPerson><ContactDetails xsi:nil="true" />
<PreferredContactMethod>NotApplicable</PreferredContactMethod>
</MessageNotification>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your text in a column and use that instead? Also, could you post your XML content.

Comment: can you explain more with xml data?

Comment: because `Request viewed` isn't encapsulated in the string, you end the string and type `Request viewed` then start the string again. so it is treating `Request viewed` as something meaningful

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, I set the searchString to "Request viewed" at the top but I get the error :Remote function reference 'dbo.HistoryData.Data.exist' is not allowed, and the column name 'dbo' could not be found or is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error are the single quotes obviously.

But I think there is more around... What are you trying to achieve?

The `exist()` is checking for the pure existance and in most cases used within a `WHERE` clause in order to reduce the rows before a more expensive operations.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES
 (N'<root>
    <a>test</a>
    <a>Some other</a>
   </root>')
,(N'<root>
    <a>no</a>
    <a>Some other</a>
   </root>')
,(N'<root>
    <a>no</a>
    <a>test</a>
   </root>');

SELECT * 
FROM @dummyTable
WHERE YourXML.exist(N'//*[contains(text()[1],"test")]')=1;
```

The result set comes without line 2

### UPDATE: Use a variable

In order to get this more generic I'd suggest to use a variable:

```
DECLARE @SearchFor NVARCHAR(100)='other';

SELECT * 
FROM @dummyTable
WHERE YourXML.exist(N'//*[contains(text()[1],sql:variable("@SearchFor"))]')=1;
```

This comes without line 3

Comment: this what i done : [dbo].[HistoryData].[Data].exist(N'//*[contains(text()[1],sql:variable("@@SearchText_"))]')=1  then the result is "Remote function reference 'dbo.HistoryData.Data.exist' is not allowed, and the column name 'dbo' could not be found or is ambiguous.
"

Comment: I set the variable @@SearchText_ at the top with value Request viewed

Comment: Don't use the doubled `@@` here. Try this with my reduced MCVE (the code above). Is this the same error you get on your query?

Comment: [Read this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx). A variable with `@@` **is not a *global* variable as some people think!**

Comment: the code you posted return error:Remote function reference 'dbo.HistoryData.Data.exist' is not allowed, and the column name 'dbo' could not be found or is ambiguous.

Comment: Ok got it, I removed the [dbo]